# Read a maze from a txt file in javaa

Tags: java, txt, maze

For my homework assignment I need to read a from a txt file a maze with the number of the rows and columns at the first line and the maze right under with 1 being walls and 0 being open path. I've found similar problems here in this site and got some help from one but I keep getting an exception!

The maze:

```
9 7
1 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Thiseas{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    File mazeFile = new File("C:/Users/Kristi/Desktop/project/sample_input.txt");
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mazeFile));
    String rea = read.readLine();
    String[] split = rea.split(" ");
    int width = Integer.valueOf(split[0]);
    int height = Integer.valueOf(split[1]);
    String readline;
    readline = read.readLine();
    int num = 0;
    char[][] maze1 = new char[width][height];
    while((readline = read.readLine()) != null){
        char[] ch = readline.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++){
            maze1[i][num] = ch[i];
        }
        num++;
    }
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++){
            System.out.print(maze1[i][j]+' ');
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:   > Index 9 out of bounds for length 9
> at Thiseas.main(Thiseas.java:19)

Comment: Look's like you flipped width and height, also you are reading the space in the line (ie: `ch.length` count the spaces), you should [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348182) it along space characters.

Comment: I see but how will I implement the split there

Comment: There is actually already a `split` call in _your_ code...

Comment: yes but do i need to change the toCharArray line? because im using the split but it shows the same exception

Answer (score 0):

before the while loop, you are doing a read line because of that readline one line is getting skipped. I think if you remove that it will solve your problem.

Comment: ye I corrected that but It's not the porblem aparrently I read the spaces too inside the while But I do not know how to remove them